# NSTimer doesn't pass arguments to the selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nstimer

I create an `NSTimer`:

```
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(createObject:)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];
```

and `createObject:` is defined as follows:

```
- (void)createObject:(ccTime) dt{

    int r = arc4random() % 4;


    for (int i=0; i < r; i++) {

    character[charIndex] = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"o.png"];

    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is to send some variables into the method. I rewrote the function as:

```
- (void)createObject:(ccTime) dt cID:(int)cID {

    int r = arc4random() % 4;


    for (int i=0; i < r; i++) {

    character[cID] = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"o.png"];

    }
}
```

but I can't pass the variable `cID` to the function from the timer. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

according to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Articles/usingTimers.html) methods that are called from a NSTimer need a signature like this:

```
- (void)timerFireMethod:(NSTimer*)theTimer
```

It is not possible to provide custom parameters, or more than one parameter.

---

So rewrite your timer method so it uses the userInfo of the NSTimer

```
- (void)createObject:(NSTimer *)timer {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [timer userInfo];
    int cID = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"cID"] intValue];
    /* ... */
}
```

create a userInfo and then start the timer like this:

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt:cID], @"cID",
                          /* ... */
                          nil];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(createObject:)
                               userInfo:userInfo
                                repeats:YES];
```

Comment: 5 secs sooner than my answer which say the same thing in other word, +1 :)

Comment: The only valid signature [according to the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Articles/usingTimers.html) is `- (void)meth: (NSTimer *)tim`. The no-parameter version does seem to work, but it is not correct.

Answer (score 7):

Your selector must have this [signature](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) :

```
- (void)timerFireMethod:(NSTimer*)theTimer
```

But there is a concept of UserInfo in Cocoa

> userInfo :
>   The user info for the timer. The object you specify is retained by the timer and released when the timer is invalidated. This parameter may be nil.

So in clear you can use that to pass information to the method that is call by the timer and from that method you can access the UserInfo.

```
information = [theTimer userInfo];
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful but when I try to send an int value using the userInfo parameter it gives me an error!!! how am I suppose to send the info?

Comment: It must be an object so you need to boxe it in an NSNunber

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method to using `+scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` is to use [+scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:invocation:repeats:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000319-CHDBFDJF).  An [NSInvocation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSInvocation) can wrap any method signature and parameters.  It is however, more complicated to set up than just setting userInfo to a dictionary containing the things you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass your parameters with userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:parameterObj1, @"keyOfParameter1"...

A simple example:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(handleTimer:) userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:9], @"parameter1", nil] repeats:YES];


-(void) handleTimer:(NSTimer *)timer{


    int parameter1 = [[[timer userInfo] objectForKey:@"parameter1"] integerValue];

    if(parameter1>0){

        [timer invalidate];
        timer=nil;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The userInfo parameter has to be an object.  Other data types ( such as a C data tyoe) need to be wrapped inside an object, or dictionary or array of objects.